# Empty Query Results after switching API KEY - CA Agile Rally API

Tags: rally

I'm running into a strange issue where I'm getting no results from queries to the [CA Agile Rally API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) after switching to a new API key. Both API keys are created on subscription admin accounts and the queries are exactly the same so I'm not sure why I would have this issue.

It is really the strangest thing and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it further. The issue only seems to affect queries that return 1 result (i.e query by ObjectID/ObjectUUID). Other queries with more than 1 result seem to be working as expected (unless it's an OR query with multiple ObjectID/ObjectUUIDs). I've also confirmed that I can get/update the artifact using the ref without a problem. When I switch back to my old API key and run the exact same query I get the desired result.

I'm using [this package](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide) but I've also tested with my own Node JS request API calls and I have the same problem. What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to give the user a default workspace/project and it resolved the issue.